# Is there any way to "name" or "tag" a LINQ query so that it can be identified by a tool like Ignite SQL easier?

Tags: sql-server, linq

Our team is moving towards LINQ, but one of the problems we've run up against is that you cannot easily identify where a LINQ query is coming from using tools like Ignite SQL.

Previously we have been using Stored Procedures, which are easy to track with Ignite.  Find a problem Query, find the Stored Procedure that uses it, find the code that calls that Stored Procedure.

With LINQ, when a trouble Query shows up...we have no way to identify what is actually executing that code.

We are looking for a way to "tag" or "name" a LINQ query, so that we can better track our trouble queries back to code.

Comment: Looks like it is still supported with LINQ http://www.devart.com/linqinsight/entity-framework-profiler.html

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this. I would require a special command on top of the already leaky abstraction of `IQueryable` that EF implements. Something like `db.Entities.Select(...).Name("Query1")`. There are two alternatives (that I can think of).

1. By far the best option is to look at the query closely and try to *reason* it back to to point in the application it comes from. Why is this the best option? Because by doing this you gain insight in the kind of queries EF generates from which kind of LINQ statements. Soon you'll see a query and think ah, this must be a `GroupBy`, that must be an `Any`, etc. Together with the table and column names it should be possible to find the culprit.
2. The typical software developer's option, so inherently lazy and by definition not the best one: create a command interceptor that executes a special `SELECT` after EF's SQL commands.

```cs
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception;

...

public class StackTraceCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
{
    public override void ReaderExecuted(
                             DbCommand command, 
                             DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        if (command.CommandText.StartsWith("SELECT"))
        {
            var cmd = command.Connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT '{0}'", 
                                        new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(17));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

And somewhere in your application startup:

```
DbInterception.Add(new StackTraceCommandInterceptor());
```

As you can see, after each `SELECT` command a new command is composed that `SELECT`s a text from nothing, so the only thing it does is make itself visible in any database profiling tool (it is *not* logged by EF's own logging, by the way). The text it logs is the 18th stack frame. From a bit of trial and error with EF's the current source this appeared to contain the method that executed the LINQ statement. Maybe with other versions it is different. If necessary you can output `new System.Diagnostics.StackStrace()`, i.e. the whole stack trace.

Needless to say that this interceptor should only be activated for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: Just a thought - do you think it would be possible to change the connection string on the fly, to alter the Application Name part of the connection string to include the method name or anything else to identify the caller?

Comment: @atornblad I don't think EF does anything with this application name. But anyway, how would that tack names to individual queries?

Comment: Using the Application Name would avoid the need for extra SELECT queries, possibly giving the tracking system something to go by. You could use `System.Diagnostics.StackFrame.GetMethod` to tack on the name of the current method at the end of ApplicationName. That way, a tracking framework like Ignite might be able to show some good information.

Comment: @atornblad Maybe. I wouldn't like changing the connection string while commands are being executed though. It might even trigger MSDTC when multiple commands are executed in one `TransactionScope`.